# onListItemClick in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, oncreate

I need use onListItemClick in my class, it's an extends Fragment, I don't how can I use it in my class, somebody knows how can I call it?

```
public class VisitaFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visita, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Visitas visita = new Visitas();

        List<Visita> visitas = visita.getVisitas();
        final ListVisitaAdapter visitaAdapter = new ListVisitaAdapter(getActivity(), visitas);

        ListView listVisitas = (ListView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_visita_emvisita);
        listVisitas.setAdapter(visitaAdapter);

        //-->> onListItemClick
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listVisitas.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend android.app.ListFragment instead of Fragment. It contains an onListItemClick() method that you can override.

Comment: You're right, but a recommended way to do things much more scalable is to extend all your fragments from a custom defined class, for example something like `MyFragment`, so, in my opinion, classes such as ListFragment, ListActivity, etc., are discouraged nowadays.

Comment: I don't disagree, but he was being specific about the method he wanted to use.